# laravel php count then delete

Tags: php, laravel, count

I have a made a simple thing. If I delete sometimes I get -3 points, sometimes I get `-1` points, sometimes `-4` points. Why? My code:

```
$query = DB::table('videos')
    ->groupBy('creator_id')
    ->select('creator_id', DB::raw('COUNT(creator_id) AS count'))
    ->toSql();

DB::table('users')
    ->join(DB::raw('('.$query.') AS sq'), 'id', '=', 'creator_id')
    ->update(['my_points' => DB::raw('my_points - count')]);

$current_timestamp = Carbon::now()->timestamp;
$video->delete();
return redirect('/videos')->with('alert-success', 'Video deleted');
```

Normally it should be `-1`. What is wrong?

Comment: What is `my_points` and what is `count`? if `my_points == 3` and `count == 1`, well 3-1=2.

Comment: @ggdx can u make example how to count -1? $user->my_points--; not good, becouse if admin delete video, admin also get -1 point

Comment: Yes. `DB::raw('count - 1')]);`

Comment: thanks @ggdx u move me on the road! :)